# Browsersync reload in a loop with nunjucks task

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync, nunjucks

For some time I have a problems with Browsersync. I have a web front-end workflow with Gulp, Browsersync, SASS and Nunjucks. Gulp compile my Nunjucks files. At the end of this task, browser is reloaded with Browsersync. Before a few days browsersync reloaded browser just once. Now it reload browser as many times as there are nunjucks files.

- Browsersync [  2.13.0  ]
- Node        [  6.9.1  ]
- Npm         [  4.0.2  ]
- windows
- Gulp

  ```
  gulp.task('njk', function () {
      return gulp.src(templatesInput)
          .pipe(nunjucksRender({
              path: templatesFolder,
              ext:  '.html'
          }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest(templatesOutput))
          .pipe(browserSync.stream());
  });

  gulp.task('serve', function () {
      browserSync.init({
          server: {
              baseDir: render
          }
      });


      // Watch Sass
      gulp.watch(scssInput, ['css']).on('change', function (event) {
          console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
      });

      // Watch nunjuck
      gulp.watch(templatesInput, ['njk']).on('change', function (event) {
          console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
      });
  });

  gulp.task('default', ['serve', 'css', 'njk']);
  ```

I specify that my files are in folders and in subfolders.

```
var templatesFolder = siteSources + 'templates/';
var templatesInput = templatesFolder + '**/*.njk';
```

I did test again. I added a task that launches njk task once it is finished.

```
gulp.task('njk-watch', ['njk'], function (done) {
        browserSync.reload();
    done();
});
```

And I call this task in my watcher. But doesn't work, reloading it's not done. Strange because it's the recommended method in the doc https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-reload

If I remove 'return' on my main task 'njk'. In this case there is no more multiple reloading. But the reloading is before the end of the njk task.

```
gulp.task('njk', function () {
    gulp.src(templatesInput)
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
        ....
```

For the moment the only way is to remove return on 'njk task' and add a setTimeout but I think there is a best method.

```
gulp.task('njk', function () {
    gulp.src(templatesInput)
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
            path: templatesFolder,
            ext:  '.html'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(templatesOutput));
});

// Reload browser after 2.5s
gulp.task('njk-watch', ['njk'], function (done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        browserSync.reload();
    }, 2500);
    done();
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `.pipe(browserSync.stream());` with `.on('end', browserSync.reload);` in your original gulp task?